# Is HttpOnly cookie support built into npapi (firebreath)

Tags: firefox, plugins, npapi, firebreath

I read this article https://wiki.mozilla.org/NPAPI:HttpOnlyCookies , since the article is almost two years old, has it been implemented in NPAPI or Firebreath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not listed as an accepted proposal on [the main NPAPI page](https://wiki.mozilla.org/NPAPI), so it's never become part of NPAPI. That's why it's not in [the NPAPI headers](https://code.google.com/p/npapi-sdk/source/browse/trunk/headers/npapi.h). Given that, it's unlikely any browser implements it. Chromium certainly hasn't, and mxr doesn't show any indication of `NPNURLVHttpOnlyCookie` in Gecko either. (Not surprising, since both Chromium and Mozilla contributors argued against it on the NPAPI list when it was proposed.)

The age of the proposal is irrelevant given that it was not accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Support is not available in FireBreath, though it could probably be added if you wanted. I *think* support has been added to Firefox's NPAPI, don't know about Chrome. You'd have to try it.

Comment: I read about npapi support being dropped in chrome which would mean opera too, so I am looking for an alternative. I feel so bad for NPAPI/Firebreath, so much hard work being put to waste

Comment: not put to waste; it has served its purpose and I think it will take quite awhile for NPAPI to really go away. There simply aren't alternate solutions for many of the things that people use it for, even in Chrome, and definitely not for many things in FireFox